# How to fill a listview from database using an SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sdcard, simplecursoradapter

I get some data from the database and try to fill them in a listview.
i have checked through cursor.count() there is data exist but the listview show anything :/

I use a simpleCursorAdapter:

```
    rubDb.open();   
    cur = rubDb.getRubParent();     
    startManagingCursor(cur);
    Log.d("cursor length",Integer.toString(cur.getCount()));
    String[] from = new String[] { RubriqueDbAdapter.RUB_NOM, RubriqueDbAdapter.RUB_VISUEL };       
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.title, R.id.icon};
    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,  R.layout.itemgauche, cur, from, to);
    listeGauche.setAdapter(listAdapter);


public Cursor getRubParent() {              
    Cursor cursorResults = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_RUBRIQUE + " WHERE rub_id_parent = 0 ORDER BY rub_ordre ASC", null);       
    return cursorResults;
}
```

how can I get a picture from the sdcard and put it on the ImageView in the listview ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: post the getView() method from your adapter class.

Comment: I did not override getView() :s

Comment: ok, I make a customlistadapter which extends ArrayAdapter, here the getView() method, but now how to setText with the right title extract from the database? tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should be using a `CursorAdapter`, perhaps a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, instead of manually copying all of the data into objects in an array, just to use `ArrayAdapter`.

Second, if your list will be *anything* other than a simple piece of text, you *must **teach*** the adapter how to do whatever else you want. With `SimpleCursorAdapter`, you could associate a `ViewBinder` with it, or subclass `SimpleCursorAdapter` and override `setViewImage()`, or subclass `SimpleCursorAdapter` and override `bindView()`.

Comment: Ok I made some changes, can you check it please

Comment: @Remy: To use `CursorAdapter` or subclasses, you need an `_id` column in the `Cursor`. Typically, that would be the primary key of the table you are querying.